# Host Laravel Project in IIS 10 Server

Tags: laravel-6, iis-10

I am hosting my Laravel project on IIS 10 server, everything was running well， but when I try on my API, I realise whenever my post request contains files, API will just return 500 Error, but without file is working, does anyone met this issue before?

Appreciate that, if you could share me and guide me to solve this.

Comment: manage to solve it by open the permission for temp folder.

Comment: Then post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by open the permission for C:\Windows\Temp folder, due to IIS user no permission to upload file to this temp folder before move to the desire folder.

Hope this solution can help, whoever facing this problem.